# Configure routes in C# server for React.js frontend web application

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I have started playing around with react.js as a frontend web app and C# Web API and now I want to figure out how to set up the routes.

The current behavior:

- When I run the server the application loads correctly with url:
  *localhost:port/page1*
- I can switch between pages in navigation bar easily. The url in browser is switching between *localhost:port/page1*,
  *localhost:port/page2* and *localhost:port/page3*
- However if I enter for example *localhost:port/page3* directly I will get `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI localhost:port/page3`

Can you please explain why using nav bar in react I can get the url correctly but when I enter it directly it will fail?

**RouteConfig.cs (C# WebApi)**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "*",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
    }
```

**routes.js (react app)**
where `domu` is page1, `pacienti` is page2 and `tagy` is page3

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute, Redirect, IndexRedirect, hashHistory } from 'react-router'


import Layout from './components/utils/layout';
import Domu from './pages/domu';
import Pacienti from './pages/pacienti';
import Tagy from './pages/tagy';

const routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route history={hashHistory} path="/" component={Layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Domu}/>
            <IndexRedirect to="domu" />
            <Route path="domu" component={Domu}/>
            <Route path="pacienti" component={Pacienti}/>
            <Redirect from="*" to="pacienti" />
            <Route path="tagy" component={Tagy}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

**header.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';


export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Navbar inverse>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <span style={{paddingLeft: '1em'}}>FNO - Urgent</span>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav>
                    <LinkContainer to="/Domu">
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#/domu">Domu</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/Pacienti">
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#/pacienti">Pacienti</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/Tagy">
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#/tagy">Tagy</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                </Nav>

            </Navbar.Header>
            <Nav pullRight>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Logout</NavItem>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
source codes available here: https://github.com/trannann/reactUrgent

Comment: Are you using React Router ?

Comment: yes - `"react-router": "^3.0.2"` also `react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1"`

Comment: So first all think about what 'SinglePageApplication' stand for. You just need to handle the first call using MVC controller, then use ReactRouter to navigate through components. Refer to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/Introduction.md

Comment: <a href="#/about">About</a> are you using the hash?

Comment: You are missing <Router history={hashHistory}>

Comment: try use <Link to="/Domu">Domu</Link>

Comment: and please post Layout and Domu componenst code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148584/discussion-between-stefano-vuerich-and-pandemic).