# React ignores .NET 5 routing

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, .net-5

I'm trying to call an API action in the .NET 5 controller from a React front end; however, the fetch is using React routing instead of .NET routing, and I'm not sure why.

Everything I've Googled shows my startup is setup correctly, but I've debugged and I know that the controller is never being called. Instead the fetch is pulling the index.html page from React.

I've not used a React front end with .NET before and I'm at a loss why React is ignoring the .NET routing.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers(options => {
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            });

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            services.Configure<ReviewFolder>(Configuration.GetSection("ReviewFolder"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
                );
            });
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetFilesController : ControllerBase {
        ReviewFolder folderPath;

        public GetFilesController(ReviewFolder folder) {
            folderPath = folder;
        }

        [Produces("application/json", new string[] {"text/json"})]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetReviewFilesList() {
            try {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath.path);

                return new JsonResult(new {files = files});
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                return new JsonResult(new {error = e.ToString()});
            }
        }
    }
```

React JS call

```
        try {
            let response = await fetch("/api/GetFiles/GetReviewFilesList", {method: "GET", headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}});
            console.log(response);
            let files = await response.json();
            console.log(files)
    /*
            if (files.error) {
                this.props.handleError(files.error);
            }
            else {
                this.setState({loading: false, files: files.files});
            }
    */
        }
        catch (e) {
            this.props.handleError(e);
        }
```

Comment: Q: So you're confused why your React app is using React routing?  Useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964918/: `So first all think about what 'SinglePageApplication' stand for. You just need to handle the first call using MVC controller, then use ReactRouter to navigate through components. `

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console browser window for the value of the response object and using that to trigger the API endpoint using PostMan?

Comment: The response is returning the index.html page, where I'm expecting JSON from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Add /api to the context array in setupProxy.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With a Single Page Application (SPA) the server will only return a single HTML page  that is required to "start up" your application.

Once that first page is returned, the SPA framework (in this case React.js) will "take over" everything else, including routing.

The SPA application simply makes requests to the server for JSON data and uses react-router to "navigate" through the application.

Comment: In a React app with an Express server, I was using fetch to pull data from server side, passed back to the front end. In this case, I need to pull files from the server side, which is what the controller is doing, and pass it back to the front end. How do I achieve that? Should I scrap React and go with regular MVC?

Answer (score 0):

From comment:

> Instead the fetch is pulling the index.html page from React.

That usually happens when you try to call an API-Endpoint that doesn't exist.

Instead of this

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
 name: "default",
 pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
);
```

Try this

```
endpoints.MapControllers();
```

For further reading about the whole routing shenanigans:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis

Answer (score 0):

Check your React App's `index.js` and try removing a `registerServiceWorker()` call from it, if it exists.

If it was there, also go into your browser's Developer Tools and remove the registered Service Worker from there too (it's under the Application tab in Chrome).

The service worker is part of the default React template for .NET, but it will cause issues like this, where your .NET-based routing is bypassed by the browser and sent immediately to your React application instead.